# How to download and install Microsoft's Visual Studio C/C++ compiler without Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-c++

I'm trying to run C code on my Windows, but I have a low-end PC, and I don't think I *should* install Visual Studio.

How do I only install the C/C++ compiler that comes with it, without installing Visual Studio itself.

Answer (score 13):

What you want is called the "Windows SDK", which contains everything you need to build applications on Windows, except the IDE (Visual Studio).

It comes with all necessary libraries, header files, a compiler, nmake et cetera, and a handy shortcut for a preconfigured `cmd.exe` that puts all of these tools in your `PATH`. If you know what you are doing, this is what you want to use.

What version of the SDK you want depends on the system you are compiling on, but you will find all of them on the Microsoft website. For Windows 10 for example, the SDK can be found here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk

Be aware, though, that the windows' compiler `cl.exe` can be a bit tricky at times, and nmake is not what you expect when you only learned GNUmake. If all you want is to compile on Windows, without having to drag 20+ Gigabytes of IDE around, then the SDK is an option to consider.

(We are using virtual machines with a preinstalled Windows SDK quite successfully in lectures and exercises.)

---

As of Windows 8 the SDK no longer contains the build tools for C++ based applications. These are now only contained in a Visual Studio installation.

Comment: Should anyone stumble here in 2022, here's instructions one can read in the VSCode online documentation: From the Visual Studio Downloads page, scroll down until you see Tools for Visual Studio 2022 under the All Downloads section and select the download for Build Tools for Visual Studio 2022. (Still a ~6GB download...)

Answer (score 9):

You can download the compiler and related stuff as part of the Visual Studio Build Tools.  The 2017 version is here:

https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017

Comment: Be sure to select on a per-component basis (will make sense when you open the installer) because by default even if you select nothing it tries to also install .NET6 and some MSV stuff totaling about 13 GiB. Un-select that, and in my case only select the Windows 10 SDK for a total install size of around 2 GiB.